# Literature on Mayan mathematics

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, astronomy, geometry

I [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3664182/588411) this question on math.se and they sent me here.

It is well known that Mayan people [used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_numerals) vigesimal (base 20) numeral system, and had had an advanced [calendar system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_calendar).

Except for these facts, I'm couldn't find any more information about Mayan mathematics. I would like to know a little bit more about Mayan geometry or astronomy. Does someone know a good resource which could be a good starting point for my research?

P.S. While researching this topic, I have seen that there is a lot of resources that are almost pseudo-scientific. Of course, I'm not interested in these references.

Comment: For Mayan Geometry, here are a few links that may possibly help: <https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/maya-geometry-in-the-classroom-special-ratios-in-maya-architecture> <https://www.mayaexploration.org/themes_geometry.php> For Mayan Astronomy here are a few links that may possibly help: <https://www.historymuseum.ca/cmc/exhibitions/civil/maya/mmc07eng.html> <https://www.thoughtco.com/ancient-maya-astronomy-2136314>